huggingface optimum circular dependency issue
I have a fresh virtual env where I am trying to exec an onnx model like so:
# Load Locally Saved ONNX Model and use for inference
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForCustomTasks

sentence = "This is a test sentence."
local_onnx_model = ORTModelForCustomTasks.from_pretrained("./model_onnx")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./model_onnx")
inputs = tokenizer(
    sentence,
    padding="longest",
    return_tensors="np",
)
outputs = local_onnx_model.forward(**inputs)
print(outputs)

but it ouputs this annoying error:
The cache for model files in Transformers v4.22.0 has been updated. Migrating your old cache. This is a one-time only operation. You can interrupt this and resume the migration later on by calling `transformers.utils.move_cache()`.
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
2024-05-18 03:36:29.312177: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-05-18 03:36:29.888001: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1510, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/onnx/__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ...commands.export.onnx import parse_args_onnx
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/commands/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .export import ExportCommand, ONNXExportCommand, TFLiteExportCommand
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/commands/export/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .base import ExportCommand
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/commands/export/base.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .onnx import ONNXExportCommand
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/commands/export/onnx.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ...exporters import TasksManager
ImportError: cannot import name 'TasksManager' from partially initialized module 'optimum.exporters' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1510, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/onnx/graph_transformations.py", line 19, in <module>
    import onnx
  File "/home/foo/new_virtual_env/rezatec_cpy/src/onnx.py", line 1, in <module>
    from optimum.exporters.onnx import main_export
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1075, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1500, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1512, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import optimum.exporters.onnx.__main__ because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'TasksManager' from partially initialized module 'optimum.exporters' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1510, in _get_module
    return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/onnxruntime/modeling_ort.py", line 61, in <module>
    from ..exporters import TasksManager
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .tasks import TasksManager  # noqa
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/tasks.py", line 139, in <module>
    class TasksManager:
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/tasks.py", line 297, in TasksManager
    "clip-text-model": supported_tasks_mapping(
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/tasks.py", line 111, in supported_tasks_mapping
    importlib.import_module(f"optimum.exporters.{backend}.model_configs"), config_cls_name
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/onnx/model_configs.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ...onnx import merge_decoders
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1075, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1500, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1512, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import optimum.onnx.graph_transformations because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import optimum.exporters.onnx.__main__ because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'TasksManager' from partially initialized module 'optimum.exporters' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/new_virtual_env/rezatec_cpy/src/onnx2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from optimum.onnxruntime import ORTModelForSequenceClassification
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1075, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1500, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
  File "/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1512, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import optimum.onnxruntime.modeling_ort because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import optimum.onnx.graph_transformations because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import optimum.exporters.onnx.__main__ because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'TasksManager' from partially initialized module 'optimum.exporters' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/foo/miniconda3/envs/new_virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/__init__.py)

Its a new env and I have run:
pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy --no-cache-dir eager optimum[exporters,onnxruntime]
as per the docs to install the pkg.
Totally lost!

JC it was because my inference file was named onnx.py  changed that and the problem dissapeared. Only spent 12 hours on it!
